# How can I map the XPath in Selenium?

Tags: java, dom, xpath, selenium

I am currently trying to map the highlighted line shown below in the screen grab.
I've looked at w3schools and looked it up here on SO but cant seem to get my code right.. My selenium script keeps erroring out with cannot identify element.

[image: xpath for highlighted line]

currently, I am doing something like:

`selenium.click("xpath=//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr[@class='level3']/td[@id='resultTable_0_0_1_ob']/span/a[@class='linkOnly']");`

I have also tried this:

`selenium.click("xpath=//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody[1]/tr[6]/td[2]/span[1]/a[1]");`

and this:

`selenium.click("xpath=//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/span/a");`

Am I doing it right and I just need to put in a delay ? or am I doing this completely wrong ?

---

EDIT:

Here is the code snippet as requested. Thanks for the pointer, I didn't really notice that there were multiple classes with the same name! Hm, but for some reason, the other two XPaths that I wrote dont work.

In this code snippet, I expanded the table so you can better see how the table is set up. Again, sorry for the image size, but **ctrl+scroll up** should enlarge the picture.

[image: table expanded]

Comment: sorry about the screen grab size.. you can 
**ctrl+scroll up** or **ctrl+'shift='** to enlarge.. 
thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looking at the html I noticed that there were multiple <tr class="level3"> nodes, and as far as we can see from your example it's unsure whether or not that other path contains the same child nodes. Try posting just the snippet from the <table id="resultTable"> on downwards. Your XPath worked fine for me.

Comment: @JWiley
Thanks for mentioning the multiple <tr class="level3"> nodes. I didnt notice until you mentioned it.

I've edited my posted to include the expanded table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer using css selectors as they work faster (currently using webdriver + java)
so solution to your problem be like:

```
  String cssSelector = "tr[class='level3']>td[id='resultTable_0_0_1_ob']>span>a[class='linkOnly']"
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).click():
    driver.manage.timeouts.implicitWait(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

As you got ID='resultTable_0_0_1_ob'   I think this ID should help in finding unique element on the page.
**2nd way to solve your problem**:
also if framework which your site is implemented on supports jQuery you can easly use jQuery:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $("tr[class='level3']>td[id='resultTable_0_0_1_ob']>span>a[class='linkOnly'];");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

And don't forget to verify your xpaths, css selectors in firepath(firebug extension) in firefox.
Picture below provided:
[image: firepath]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! unfortunately, my web application is not compatible with firefox, but your examples made your point clear to me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

xpath=//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr[@class='level3']/td[@id='resultTable_0_0_1_ob']/span/a[@class='linkOnly']

The Corresponding CSS is css=#resultTable > tbody > tr.level3 > #resultTable_0_0_1_ob > span > .linkOnly